# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightBox'

Tags: jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I am getting this error when trying to use jQuery.LightBox:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightBox'`

Here is a live example (rebuilding a table design in divs, don't hate.):

http://www.builderpreviews32.com/photos.php

And YES, the jQuery file is referenced BEFORE the jQuery.LightBox file.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta name='keywords' content=''>
<meta name='description' content=''>
<title></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>

    <link href="/common/styles/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/common/styles/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/common/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/common/scripts/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script> 
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
<a href="/"><img src="/common/images/lgo_lake.jpg" alt="Riss Lake Logo" /></a>
<div id="nav">
    <nav>
        <a href="/about.php">About Riss Lake</a>
        <a href="/developer.php">Developer</a>
        <a href="/developer.php">Communities</a>
        <a href="/awards.php">Awards</a>
        <a href="/areamap.php">Area Map</a>
        <a href="/developer.php">Inventory</a>
        <a href="/photos.php">Photos</a>
        <a href="/builders.php">Builders</a>
        <a href="/developer.php">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="/areainfo.php">Area Information</a>
    </nav>
</div> <!-- End Nav -->
</div> <!-- End Header -->          
        <div id="body">
            <!--MODULE:image_gallery.php|CACHE:main_photos-->

            <div class="lightbox">
                                <a href="/images/uploaded/115747639443725_poolside_sm.jpg"><img src="/images/uploaded/thumb_115747639443725_poolside_sm.jpg" alt=""

                                                            width="150" 
                                                    class="photo_edge" /></a>
                                <a href="/images/uploaded/115747639443725_poolside_sm.jpg"><img src="/images/uploaded/thumb_115747639443725_poolside_sm.jpg" alt=""

                                                            width="150" 
                                                    class="photo_edge" /></a>
                                <a href="/images/uploaded/115747639443725_poolside_sm.jpg"><img src="/images/uploaded/thumb_115747639443725_poolside_sm.jpg" alt=""

                                                            width="150" 
                                                    class="photo_edge" /></a>
                                <a href="/images/uploaded/960211759433150_002.jpg"><img src="/images/uploaded/thumb_960211759433150_002.jpg" alt=""

                                                            width="150" 
                                                    class="photo_edge" /></a>
                </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$('.lightbox a').lightBox();});</script>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">Copyright © 2003. <a href="/privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/terms.php">Terms of Use</a></div>          
    </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any other error in the console, also make sure the lightbox library is in the correct path

Comment: That's the only one. Live page is linked above.

Comment: which is the plugin used

Comment: isn't it a case problem ? lightbox() instead of lightBox() ?

Comment: I think you're thinking about the wrong plugin. This one http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ does not need to be initialized like that. but this one does http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: Im using the 2nd, and calling it with: `$(function(){$('.lightbox a').lightBox();});`

Comment: @RickBross then you downloaded the wrong one. because the second one is currently at version 0.5. Also quote from the source code of the second one `This jQuery plugin was inspired and based on Lightbox 2 by Lokesh Dhakar (http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)
 * and adapted to me for use like a plugin from jQuery.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the script includes in the head section

```
<link href="/common/styles/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/common/styles/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/common/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/common/scripts/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem that I was mixing up my lightboxes, haha. Thanks for that tip though.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to resolve the issue

1. Check your script is loaded or not by using source tab in browser debugger.
2. Try putting the script immediately below jQuery include as it is dependent.

Ensure your script tags are closed.

My initial guess is, it must be due to not proper ordering of scripts, if script is properly included and loading when you debug using browsers debugger. I have also faced this issue earlier.

Good luck buddy and let me know if it works out.

Comment: This doesn't help me at all. Look at the code, you will see that is not the case, and that I stated that it is not the case above.